# Using Calculus to Solve for a Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The question I have is: $x''(t)+yx'(t)+z^2x(t)=0$, where y and z $\in \mathbb{R}$ without $0$. $t \geq 0$ by the way. The total energy of the system is $$\frac{1}{2}(x'(t))^2+ \frac{1}{2}z^2x(t)^2$$ The question is, for t > 0, under what conditions is the total energy of the system *always increasing*? Since the only things that can change are y and z, it certainly has to do with these constants. I'm just not sure what it is, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Let $ E $ be the total energy of your system.

$$E=\frac 12\Bigl((x'(t))^2+z^2(x(t))^2\Bigr)$$

$ E $ is always increasing in time if
$$\frac{dE}{dt}\ge 0$$
with
$$\frac{dE}{dt}=x'(t)\Bigl(x''(t)+z^2x(t)\Bigr)$$

$$= -y(x'(t))^2$$

So, we need the condition
$$y<0$$